# How to change string literals in Emacs (from a VIM user)

Tags: emacs

Assume that the cursor is at the top of the following file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>    
    <string name="app_name">Hello World</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
    <string name="menu_settings">Settings</string>
</resources>
```

How would one copy the last `string` element and change its values to:

```
    <string name="edit_message">Enter a message</string>
```

In VIM I would `/men<Enter>` to **get to the line**, then `Yp` to **copy it below**, then simply `ciw` to **change the `name` attribute** and `cit` to **change the value**.

Note that I am *not* interested in  making Emacs behave like VIM via the use of plugins, but rather I am interested in **learning the Emacs way of thinking**. I am intrigued with [org-mode](http://orgmode.org) and I would like to start using Emacs a bit **as it was designed to be used**.

Note also that this question is adapted from a [previous question regarding Eclipse](https://superuser.com/questions/522516/how-to-change-string-literals-in-eclipse-from-a-vim-user) as that real-world situation is very good for learning the different approaches to editing text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on your preference, I guess. Personally, I'd do

- `C-s men` which is incremental search; `men` is just the shortest substring that'll get me to the line I want to change
- `home C-k` which will get me to the beginning of the line and kill that line
- `C-y Ret C-y` which pastes the line, inserts a newline and pastes it again, leaving point at the end of the fresh line
- `C-r men`, which is incremental search backwards
- `C-M-k` which, on my machine, is bound to `kill-sexp` and will delete `menu_settings`
- type `edit_message`

Comment: Thank you, this post sums up quite a few things that I needed. I just need to find `ciw` (Change the entire word) and `ci"` (Change everything in quotes) for Emacs and I should be pretty much on my way.

Comment: [Found it](http://superuser.com/questions/124246/emacs-equivalent-to-vim-ci)!